# When I try to update or Install a program Ubuntu 19.04, an error is displayed

Tags: ppa, repository

Every time I try to update or install a package or open software center, I get an error something like

```
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/tista/adapta/ubuntu disco Release' does not have a Release file.
```

I am on latest Ubuntu 19.04.

Comment: There aren't multiple error messages but only one error message. This would help you [What can I do if a repository/PPA does not have a Release file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/866901/what-can-i-do-if-a-repository-ppa-does-not-have-a-release-file)

Answer (score 1):

There is no PPA for the `disco` version.

In `terminal`...

`cd /etc/apt` # change directory

`grep -i tista sources.list` # search in sources.list

`grep -i tista sources.list.d/*.list` # search in individual .list files

Once "tista" is found ,edit that file, and change `disco` to `cosmic`.

`sudo -H gedit /path_to_found_filename/found_filename` # edit the found file

Comment: @maxemoas Please remember to accept my answer if it was helpful. Thanks!